# CSS - border radius

Tags: html, css, border

I need to recreate an icon precisely. The one I have from font awesome isn't exactly the same, here's the difference -

[image: The one I have -]

[image: How I need it to look]

The bottom image is how I need it to look. Can I use border-radius to create the circle around the icon? How do I do that?

I have the icon coded direct from FA -

```
 <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: There is still a `chevron-circle-down` icon in fontawesome - http://fontawesome.io/icon/chevron-circle-down/

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa Are you able to change the color? White circle with a black chevron? I need it for something else.

Comment: Yes, the color of the circle can be changed just be giving `color: white` to the 'fa-chevron-circle-down' class but the color of the arrow would be the color of the background. Is that fine ? If not then you have choice but to use "stacked" icons in font-awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#000000"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-stack-1x" style="color:#ffffff"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stack icons with font awesome, so just add a circle to your icon, like this:

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

look at http://fontawesome.io/examples/ for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
 <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rounded-circle class of bootstrap 4 to do so. 
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/borders/

Or you can try giving same height and width to chevron and specify border-radius to be 50%

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this even without CSS

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down fa-2x fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
```